# Port forwarding on router that has vpn client enabled

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, openvpn

Is it possible to access device in local network from outside the network (over internet) while router on which that device is connected has openvpn client enabled?

Router is Asus AC55U

Edit:

One other thing to mention is that router is not directly connected to internet, it is connected to ISPs modem/router

Edit2:

I have port forwarding set correctly, when vpn is disabled on router, then i can access devices connected to that router from the internet, but when vpn is on, then i cannot

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem to configure a port forwarding to an internal device on a router running OpenVPN. OpeVPN uses just one port, 1194 by default, and a client is not restricted to any fixed port.

If the ISP's device is just a modem, this should work without any problems, but if that device is a router, then you have to configure a port forwarding in that router, too.

If your ISP uses carrier grad NAT and doesn't assign you a public IP address, then it is much more difficult.

Comment: I have port forwarding set correctly, when vpn is disabled on router, then i can access devices connected to that router from the internet, but when vpn is on, then i cannot

Comment: You should add that information to the question. It seems the router is sending the responses from the forwarded connection via VPN and not via internet.